# How to scroll to top a UIScrollView in ClassA from another ClassB

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I'm completely new to Xcode and Objective C but managed to get a working prototype for an app by the help of this site.  But at the moment I do not find any solutions for the following problem after nearly a day of research and trial&error.

I'm working with storyboards.

I have two classes: `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

**ClassA** has a `containerView` which holds another `ViewController` thats class is **Class B**.

This `ViewController` within the `containerView` holds an **UIScrollView** (defined in ClassB) which I want to be able to scroll to top from `ClassA`.

It works in the same class (ClassB) with this code...

`[Scroller setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];`

...but not from another class (ClassA)

How can I access the IBOutlet `UIScrollView` in `ClassB` from `ClassA` and tell it to scroll up?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the iVar as `@property`:

```
@interface ClassB : UIViewController {
    // don't define it here as iVar like: IBOutlet UIScrollView *Scroller;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *Scroller; // but define it here as property
```

You could then access the scrollView like this in `ClassA`:

```
[[instanceB Scroller] setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
```

And like this in `ClassB`

```
[_Scroller setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks Julian! What do I have to use instead of "instanceB"

Comment: This would be an instance of `ClassB`. I assume that your viewController which is contained by `containerView` and is of class `ClassB` is either an `IBOutlet` or a local iVar of `ClassA`. So you have to point to your second viewController. If you only us it in XIB and don't have an outlet, just create one.

Comment: If you don't get it, please post the interface of `ClassA` so that I can see what variable it could be.

Comment: Yes it's an IBOutlet: In the ClassA.h i wrote:

"IBOutlet UIView *RateEntryContainerView;"

The Scroller is named "ScrollerEntryDetailRate"

Comment: You would need an outlet of kind `ClassB`, so `IBOutlet ClassB *RateEntryContainerViewController` and connect it to the viewController, not the view itself.

Comment: what do you mean by "of kind ClassB"? I've added "@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIViewController *RateEntryViewController;" to the ClassB.h and tried to connect it to the ViewController but it does not connect. Do you know any tutorial or documentation? Actually I even don't know what to look for in the Apple iOS Documentation...

Comment: btw: i'm using storyboard and as far as i have read you can't make an IBOutlet of a ViewController then

Comment: I never used Storyboards or vc's in XIB so I didn't know that. But what is ClassB then?! Read your OP again, there you wrote `ClassA has a containerView which holds another ViewController thats class is Class B.` what does this actually mean then?

Comment: Solved the mystery with storyboard and container views: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321922/objective-c-how-to-invoke-method-in-container-view-controller