# Objective-c: How to invoke method in container view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

## Solution for my problem from below

with isKindOfClass. Thanks to @Julian!

```
-(void)callContainerViewController {
for (UIViewController *childViewController in [self childViewControllers])
{
    if ([childViewController isKindOfClass:[ContainerViewController class]])
    {
        //found container view controller
        ContainerViewController *cvc = (ContainerViewController *)childViewController;

        //do something with your container view viewcontroller
        [cvc callFunction];

        break;
    }
}
}
```

///

## My Problem

I'm using storyboard. I've read that the child view controller of a container view is instantiated automatically. How do I call a method within my BlueViewController from the RedViewController? I've already tried several solutions here, but nothing worked in my case.

Structure is currently:

**EntryViewController.h/.m**

**.. View**

.... other Objects

**.... Container View**

**........Container View RateViewController.h/.m**

Here's my setup so far. What do I need to do. I really want to understand how this works:

/

**EntryViewController.h**

```
@interface EntryViewController : UIViewController {
}
@end
```

/

**EntryViewController.m**

```
#import RateViewController.h
@implementation

-(IBAction)callResetScrollViewMethodFromRateViewController {
[RateViewController resetScrollView];
}

@end
```

/

**RateViewController.h**

```
@interface RateViewController : UIViewController {
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) RateViewController *_RateViewControllerProperty;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *Scroller;
@end
```

/

**RateViewController.m**

```
@implementation

-(IBAction)resetScrollView {
[_Scroller setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}

@end
```

Comment: Add some code that you tried so we can help you better. Usually you would have to add an IBOutlet that references your subview and call methods into that outlet, so the subview will catch the messages.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this unless you're talking about the `init` method. This breaks the MVC paradigm.

Comment: This is not a duplicate since this deals with a container viewcontroller (albeit the general principle is always the same - grabbing a reference to a VC - the method to do so differs)

Comment: Thanks Mario! I was wondering and comparing and testing the two cases. It's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to access the viewcontroller's child through parent's `childViewControllers` property. (Or using the segue as pointed out above).

Eg:

```
BlueViewController *bvc = self.childViewControllers[0]; //assuming you have only one child 
[bvc someMethod];
```

Comment: I've two container views in this view at the same hierachy. Does this matter?

Comment: Well, it might be at the second index of the array. childViewControllers is an NSArray. [0] is subscripting notation to access the first (zero-th index) element. So in your case it might be the second (first index) element.

Comment: Nice Answer. Saved me lots of time and effort. +1

Answer (score 2):

I usually grab the controller object in the prepareForSegue method.

Here is some code I use. Remember that my naming convention for segues is always class name + Segue, so the segue for ActionMenuVC is ActionMenuVCSegue. This way is save to grab the right view controller.

```c
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:[self.appDelegate segueIdentifierForClass:[ActionMenuVC class]]]) {
        self.actionMenuVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        self.actionMenuVC.delegate = self;
    }
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:[self.appDelegate segueIdentifierForClass:[ResizeableImageVC class]]]) {
        self.resizeableImageVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        self.resizeableImageVC.delegate = self;
        self.resizeableImageVC.visible  = NO;
   }
}
```

Comment: even if you don't perform a segue?

Comment: It always performs a segue in a container viewcontroller

Comment: Ok, than i can't use it :) i do want a method call after the view controller of the container view is not visible (resetting a scroll view to scroll to the top)

Comment: Well that you could do in container viewcontroller's `viewDidDisappear`

Comment: I do not use viewDidDisappear, because the ContainerView is part of the other view and does not disappear literally. It stays in the background.