# Container views with segmented control in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uicontainerview

I have a segmented control with three segments. "Cattle", "Sheep" and "Goats". In Sheep and Goats there is another segmented control "RFID" and "Mobs"

I have used three container views on a parent viewController, a cattleView, sheepGoatMob view and a sheepGoatRFID view which have UITableViewControllers CattleTableViewController, SheepGoatMobTableViewController and SheepGoatRfidTableViewController. The parent view contains the if statement to hide/show each view, which works okay..

The problem that I am having is that each child view needs to be able to send the info on their pages to a soap web service from a UIBarButtonItem on the parent view. My first thought was to have a "send" button in each child view but because all three views are loaded into memory when the app starts, the button doesn't know which view function to call.

**EDIT : How can I accomplish setting a button in each of the three views for the UIBarButtonItem of the parent viewController and allowing the correct function from the childViewControllers to be called?**

**Option 2:** How could I access the three childviewcontroller's function through a UIBarButtonItem on the parent viewcontroller?

Comment: Typically you use delegates to pass actions up a view hierarchy. So you would create a delegate for each containerViewController that sends the 'didTapButton' event to its delegate which would be the 'mainViewController' which then does your network call.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try and post my solution

Comment: @DBoyer The problem is that each of my functions are in the childViewControllers, not the mainViewController. I need to be able to have a button on the parentViewController to trigger these functions. At the moment I am getting:

Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x78e1caf0> on <NLISHelper.CattleTableViewController: 0x7ab3fc00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Alternatively you could just use NSNotification centre, and post a notification when the button is tapped, and each child view controller would be an observer.

Comment: I fixed my issue, I will post it asap, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to have all three views loaded into memory and be able to change which function I am calling using @Julian's response: [Objective-c: How to invoke method in container view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321922/objective-c-how-to-invoke-method-in-container-view-controller)

```
//Determine which view is showing and point to the correct child class
func sendTransactionButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
   log.debug("send transaction button called p2p")

    for childViewController in self.childViewControllers {

        if childViewController.isKindOfClass(CattleTableViewController) && containerTableViewCattle.hidden == false {

            var cattleVC = childViewController as! CattleTableViewController
            cattleVC.transactions()

        } else if childViewController.isKindOfClass(SheepGoatRfidTableViewController) && containerSheepGoatsRfid.hidden == false {

            var sheepGoatRFIDVC = childViewController as! SheepGoatRfidTableViewController
            sheepGoatRFIDVC.transactions()

        } else if childViewController.isKindOfClass(SheepGoatTableViewController) && containerTableViewSheepGoats.hidden == false {

            var sheepGoatsMob = childViewController as! SheepGoatTableViewController
            sheepGoatsMob.transactions()
        }
    }
}
```

You need to ensure that your other views are hidden or you will get a warning from xcode.